# Alamofire: I can't make two simultaneously .GET call

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Using Alamofire I'm making two calls then I call in the viewDidLoad method.
I don't understand why sometimes I get the response from both, other times only first and other only the second.

```
func firstCall() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .responseJSON { response in
             print(response.data)
             if let JSON = response.result.value {
                 print("JSON: \(JSON)")
             }
         }}

func secondCall() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .responseJSON { response in
             print(response.data)
             if let JSON = response.result.value {
                 print("JSON: \(JSON)")
             }
         }}
```

Then in viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstCall()
    secondCall()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with _sometimes I get the response from both, other times only first and other only the second_?. Alamofire handle the request asynchronously, what happens here is that one request can take more time than the other request

Comment: I know that. But the problem is that many times I receive a response only from one, even after minutes of waiting. It's really strange.

Comment: happening same with me. Most of the time response block will return the response of one api call, Although I can clearly see my request in response block and they are different but response is same

Comment: @justel how did you resolved this issue